# In ionic overlay side menu I am getting error value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to display the overlay side menu, I wrote code for that, in my code I added the menu icon in header if we click that overlay side menu is opened, and we click outside it is closing.

But if I drag the page overlay side menu is not coming, I check my code all is perfect but I am getting an error `value is undefined`, I have added the code in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5I3snGsTbqmmMVHf2sth?p=preview).

Can you please help me why I am getting error value is undefined.

Comment: You don't need to implement that yourself at the first place. See [$ionicSideMenuDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/). Ionic supports dragging somewhere to open the side menu natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this component (Angular directive), or you can get inspiration by its code:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-drawer